# How can I retrieve some fields from my Firebase database before I push any changes to it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I create a Listing object and store a bunch of fields in there. Two of the fields I need to store are the current User's email and name. I am trying to get those two fields as follows

```
        dbRef = database.getReference().child("Users").child(emailKey);
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserInfo userIn = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);
            email1 = userIn.email;
            sellerName = userIn.username;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

After this bit of code I have the line

```
    DatabaseReference temp = dbRefL.push();
    temp.setValue(l);
```

All of this code is called by me pressing a button. The first time I press the button, the entire Listing object is pushed to Firebase just the way I want it EXCEPT the user email and username aren't there because they're blank. The second time I press the button the Strings are there how I want.

My guess is that this is because OnDataChange only executes after I push the Listing object. Is this true? How can I get OnDataChange to execute before I push the listing object?

Comment: i think you should put your ValueEventListener outside of your on buttom clicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

The listener `onDataChange()` callbacks are asynchronous. The reason that your email and username is blank is because `onDataChange` hasn't been executed yet to make sure you push data after email and username are retrieve, put the code inside `onDataChange()`

```
dbRef = database.getReference().child("Users").child(emailKey);
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserInfo userIn = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);
            email1 = userIn.email;
            sellerName = userIn.username;

            //set up your l value
            DatabaseReference temp = dbRefL.push();
            temp.setValue(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Once you press the button above code should be called to obtain email and username then push the data as you want.

Answer (score 0):

User addValueEvenListener like :

```
 DatabaseReference map = database.getReference("field_name");
    map.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String data = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

---

```
                           ****OR using****


database.getReference("field_name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Field data", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read user", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```